# Mocking Axios with Jest in React - mock function not being called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest for unit testing. Part of the testing is to mock Axios, but for some reason it is not being called.

Here is my `/__mocks__/axios.js` code:

```
export default {
  post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
};
```

Here is my test code:

```
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/auth';
import user from '../fixtures/user';


describe('Register User', () => {
  test('Should call register API and redirect to login', async () => {
    const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };

    mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());

    await registerUser(user, historyMock);

    expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });
});
```

Also here is the registerUser code:

```
export const registerUser = (user, history) => dispatch => axios
  .post('/users/register', user)
  .then(() => history.push('/login'))
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch(handleError(err));
  });
```

But for some reason I continue to get the error:

```
Register User › Should call register API and redirect to login

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

      35 |     await registerUser(user, historyMock);
      36 | 
    > 37 |     expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Any ideas why the mock is not working?

Comment: `registerUser` returns a *function*, which isn't being called.

Comment: great catch! I missed that in my response

Comment: @jonrsharpe from the /__mocks__/axios.js isn't it returning an empty promise though? I assumed the process would do the POST call (returning an empty promise) and then continue on with the registerUser.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the mocked method returns - as you're seeing, it never gets called. You need to invoke the function returned from `registerUser` with a test-doubled `dispatch`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you show a little more about what you mean as an answer. I think you mean that the '() => history.push('/login')' is not being called. But It should though since the 'mockAxios.post' call is returning a resolved promise that would trigger the 'then( )' clause, right?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. `axios.post` isn't getting called, so the things chained onto the promise it returns certainly aren't. This is exactly what the test failure is telling you: *"it was called zero times"*, so it's pointless to spend time looking into whether what it would return if it did get called is the right thing or not. Look at what `registerUser` actually returns; it's not a promise, *it's a function*.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe! After staring blankly at the code, I also noticed that the `registerUser` function returned the function containing dispatch as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, the registerUser function was returning the function:

```
dispatch => axios
  .post('/users/register', user)
  .then(() => history.push('/login'))
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch(handleError(err));
  });
```

So in order for this to work, I had to had to mock the store using the [redux-mock-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store) npm module. The new test code looks like:

```
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { setCurrentUser, registerUser } from '../../actions/auth';
import user from '../fixtures/user';

const defaultStoreState = { errors: {}, auth: { isAuthenticated: false, user: {} } };
const createMockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

describe('Register User', () => {
  test('Should call register API and redirect to login', (done) => {
    const mockStore = createMockStore(defaultStoreState);
    const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };

    mockStore.dispatch(registerUser(user, historyMock)).then(() => {
      expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(historyMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(historyMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This gives a passing test now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're setting the mock correctly.

```
mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce
```

should be changed to

```
mockAxios.post = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('bloofblurg');
```

Then you can double-check that `post` has been called once and resolved the expected value.

```
expect(mockAxios.post).resolves.toBe('bloofblurg');
```

*see*

1. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue
2. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves