# Mock Axios to test .catch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I have been trying to write tests to test a axios call but now need to test the `catch` part.

I have been able to do the then by mocking axios like so but can't seem to get a way to test catch. I have followed many different examples from stack overflow and the web.

```
jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData })));
```

but that will always return a good result so can't test the catch. The bit of code I want to test is: `goToUrl()` is just a `window.location.assign(url)` but imported.

```
fetchBundlesFromApi(params)
  .then(({ data: { bundles } }) => {
    updateBundles(bundles);
    this.setState({ showUpdatingPrices: false });
  })
  .catch(() => goToUrl(bundlesUrl));
```

In my test for `.then()` part I do this:

```
const fetchedBundles = await fetchBundlesFromApi(
  '?params',
);
expect(fetchedBundles.data).toEqual(mockData);
```

However if I follow examples like this one [Mocking Axios with Jest in React - mock function not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930968/mocking-axios-with-jest-in-react-mock-function-not-being-called) I can't manually mock `get` if I put a mock axios file in a folder `__mocks__` then a lot of the test suit fails so I just want to mock it in this one test file.

here is one of the examples I tried doing:

```
    jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData })),
  default: () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData })),
}));
```

but the tests error with `TypeError: (0 , _axios.default) is not a function`

EDIT:

Here is my fetchBundlesApi function:

```
const fetchBundlesFromApi = params => axios(`${bundleRoute}/bundles${params}`);
```

EDIT: catch test

```
    it('should redirect if api fails', async () => {
    const networkError = new Error('Some network error');
    axios.mockRejectedValueOnce(networkError);
    const goToUrl = jest.fn();
    let error;

    try {
      await fetchBundlesFromApi('?params');
    } catch (err) {
      error = err;
    }

    expect(error).toEqual(networkError);
    expect(goToUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

in my component I import `goToUrl` like so:

`import { goToUrl } from 'Helpers';`

Comment: Have you tried `Promise.reject` instead of `Promise.resolve` ?

Comment: I haven't tried that because if i do that, then my current test will fail

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make use of Jests ability to pop implementations off once they've run i.e. [mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvalueoncevalue) and friends.

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

// default implementation
axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockedData);

describe('#fetchBundlesFromApi', () => {
  it('returns data from API', async () => {
    const fetchedBundles = await fetchBundlesFromApi('?params');
    expect(fetchedBundles.data).toEqual(mockData);
  });
  it('redirects on failure', () => {
    // override behaviour for this one call
    axios.get.mockRejectedValueOnce();
    // verify your failure test
  });
});
```

Comment: hey, ive tried that but i get an error saying ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` i tried changing the resolved value to a promise but still the same issue. I've just updated my question with my fetch function so you can see what it is doing

Comment: @saunders so looks like you don't call any explicit function i.e. `get`, you seem to just rely on default behaviour from axios. You can either change the mock to `axios.mockResolvedValue(...)` or you can change your code to be more explicit `axios.get('...:)`

Comment: thanks that worked for the good path but I've just tried the catch part and it seems to resolve to my mockData. ```axios.mockRejectedValueOnce(Promise.reject(new Error('something bad happened')));```

But in the test it is saying it received the ```mockData``` array

Comment: I have tried quite a few different things but I cant seem to call ```goToUrl()``` it keeps saying ```Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called``` I have edited my question to include the code I have which isn't quite working

Comment: @saunders no problem, let me take a look

Comment: thanks I have just added how to include that function in my component as well to give you a bit of context

Comment: @saunders Your test seems confused - is this a unit test or an integration test? If it's a unit test then testing that X function is called on error doesn't really make sense as it's not part of the `fetchBundlesFromApi`. If you want to test that as part of an integration test then you shouldn't be directly invoking `fetchBundlesFromApi`. If you can clarify exactly what it is you are looking to test here I can update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202015/discussion-between-saunders-and-james).

Comment: WHile testing failure scenario I am seeing this error. `thrown: undefined

      at _getError (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:566:18)`