# How simulate request errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios

So, I read the article: ["How to Handle API Errors"](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-handle-api-errors-in-your-web-app-using-axios-b32b6c41fd35)

In this article, it is proposed to divide errors into:

```
if (err.response) { 
      // client received an error response (5xx, 4xx)
    } else if (err.request) { 
      // client never received a response, or request never left 
    } else { 
      // anything else 
    }
```

Ok, but how i can test this?

- Response errors are pretty easy. I use Mokku chrome extension.
- Else errors i can simulate with chrome dev tools 'network request
  blocking' tab.

But what about request Errors?
How can i simulate this error on frontend?

Comment: Inspect element > Network tab > Throttling: No throttle --> change to Offline.
By doing this, your http request will have a request but don't have any response because the network is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a testing framework, which could be something like Jest.
Using a testing framework, you can mock the request to return an error you choose.

Heres a post with an answer which might be the same as your issue.

[Mock Axios to test .catch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747896/mock-axios-to-test-catch)